# PDO MySQL update statement does not effect

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use two PHP files, one `a_ndryshoje_produktin.php` for posting data to be updated and one another `produkti_ndryshuar.php` that executes the posted data for update.

The problem for my question is that the file `produkti_ndryshuar.php` does execute without errors but there isn't any update of only the `produkti_id` with the `produkti_i_ri_id` on MySQL produktet table.

Below is my code for both files.

Thank you

```
echo "<form action='produkti_ndryshuar.php' method='post'>";

                            echo "<table class='tbl_manevro'>";

                                echo "<tr><td class='titujt'>";
                                echo "ID";
                                echo "</td></tr>";

                                echo "<tr><td>";
                                echo "<input type='text' name='produkti_i_ri_id' maxlength='60' value='".$row['produkti_id']."' />";
                                echo "</td></tr>";

                                echo "<tr><td class='titujt'>";
                                echo "Kategoria";
                                echo "</td></tr>";

                                echo "<tr><td>";
                                echo "<input type='text' name='kategori_id' maxlength='60' value='".$row['kategori_id']."' />";
                                echo "</td></tr>";

                                echo "<tr><td class='titujt'>";
                                echo "Emri";
                                echo "</td></tr>";

                                echo "<tr><td>";
                                echo "<input type='text' name='produkti_emri' maxlength='60' value='".$row['produkti_emri']."' />";
                                echo "</td></tr>";

                                echo "<tr><td class='titujt'>";
                                echo "Çmimi";
                                echo "</td></tr>";

                                echo "<tr><td>";
                                echo "<input type='text' name='produkti_cmimi' maxlength='60' value='".$row['produkti_cmimi']."' />";
                                echo "</td></tr>";

                                echo "<tr><td class='titujt'>";
                                echo "Fotografia";
                                echo "</td></tr>";

                                echo "<tr><td>";
                                echo "<input type='text' name='produkti_fotografia' maxlength='60' value='".$row['produkti_fotografia']."' />";
                                echo "</td></tr>";


                                echo "<input type='hidden' name='produkti_id' value=".$row['produkti_id']." />";


                                echo "<tr><td>";
                                echo "<input class='shtoje_btn' type='submit' value='Ndryshoje produktin' />";
                                echo "</td></tr>";  

                            echo "</table>";

                        echo "</form>";
```

and the other file produkti_ndryshuar.php :

```
$produkti_i_ri_id=strip_tags($_POST['produkti_i_ri_id']);

$kategori_id=strip_tags($_POST['kategori_id']);
$produkti_emri=strip_tags($_POST['produkti_emri']);
$produkti_cmimi=strip_tags($_POST['produkti_cmimi']);
$produkti_fotografia=strip_tags($_POST['produkti_fotografia']);
$produkti_id=strip_tags($_POST['produkti_id']);

if($produkti_i_ri_id && $kategori_id && $produkti_emri && $produkti_cmimi && $produkti_fotografia ){

    $db=include('dbconnect.php');

    $query_2=$db->prepare("update produktet set
                            produkti_id=:produkti_i_ri_id,
                            kategori_id=:kategori_id,
                            produkti_emri=:produkti_emri,
                            produkti_cmimi=:produkti_cmimi,
                            produkti_fotografia=:produkti_fotografia
                            where produkti_id=:produkti_id");

    $query_2->execute(array(':produkti_i_ri_id'=>$produkti_i_ri_id,
        ':kategori_id'=>$kategori_id,
        ':produkti_emri'=>$produkti_emri,
        ':produkti_cmimi'=>$produkti_cmimi,
        ':produkti_fotografia'=>$produkti_fotografia,
        ':produkti_id'=>$produkti_id));

    echo "<span class='lajmi_sakte'>Produkti i caktuar u ndryshua me sukses.</span>";

}
```

Comment: Note: `strip_tags()` you don't need those; you're using a prepared statement.

Comment: `$db=include('dbconnect.php');` is most likely the problem here and whatever's inside that file.

Comment: do you see your message on the page `Produkti i caktuar u ndryshua me sukses` ?

Comment: @Al.G. they're using PDO, not mysqli_.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks for the correction. To the OP: why do you return success message without even checking whether the update was successful? To check this you'll need http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php. How do you expect to get errors if you just print 'success'? (This is at least what google translate says about your message)

Comment: @Alex. Yes I see that message Produkti... I also should say here that the kategori_id, cmimi_id... updates, but the problem is only with the produkti_id (it does not updates with produkti_i_ri_id)

Comment: so you have produkti_id : $produkti_id (old) change to $produkti_i_ri_id (new)?

Comment: @ Alex Sorry for the late response, I was to busy these days. $produkti_id is the old one which has to be changed with $produkti_i_ri_id the new one.

Comment: @ Alex Sorry for the late response, I was to busy these days. $produkti_id is the old one which has to be changed with $produkti_i_ri_id the new one. The ids are primary key data and from my junior mysql point of view I think that that the primary key cant be changed from a html form even. Finaly I think that I solved this problem when I added another table column with the name ID like primary key and after this the $produkti_id old can be changed with the new one $produkti_i_ri_id. Correct me if you think that this isnt he right solution. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

You are giving values to your if statement, not booleans.
Try `isset()` :

```
               $produkti_i_ri_id=strip_tags($_POST['produkti_i_ri_id']);

                $kategori_id=strip_tags($_POST['kategori_id']);
                $produkti_emri=strip_tags($_POST['produkti_emri']);
                $produkti_cmimi=strip_tags($_POST['produkti_cmimi']);
                $produkti_fotografia=strip_tags($_POST['produkti_fotografia']);
                $produkti_id=strip_tags($_POST['produkti_id']);

                if(isset($produkti_i_ri_id) && isset($kategori_id) && isset($produkti_emri) && isset($produkti_cmimi) && isset($produkti_fotografia) ){

                    $db=include('dbconnect.php');

                    $query_2=$db->prepare("update produktet set
                                            produkti_id=:produkti_i_ri_id,
                                            kategori_id=:kategori_id,
                                            produkti_emri=:produkti_emri,
                                            produkti_cmimi=:produkti_cmimi,
                                            produkti_fotografia=:produkti_fotografia
                                            where produkti_id=:produkti_id");

                    $query_2->execute(array(':produkti_i_ri_id'=>$produkti_i_ri_id,
                                            ':kategori_id'=>$kategori_id,
                                            ':produkti_emri'=>$produkti_emri,
                                            ':produkti_cmimi'=>$produkti_cmimi,
                                            ':produkti_fotografia'=>$produkti_fotografia,
                                            ':produkti_id'=>$produkti_id));

                    echo "<span class='lajmi_sakte'>Produkti i caktuar u ndryshua me sukses.</span>";

                }
                else{

                    echo "<span class='lajmi_mink'>Ju lutemi plotësoni të gjitha fushat!!!</span>";

                }
```

And why are you using `strip_tags()` function?

Comment: What about the `include`?

Comment: @Jay include is Ok